# How to remove curly brackets from Text widget which get a list from a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm struggling with some problem for few days. I've tried many things and cannot get a list of strings without curly brackets ({}) between the texts which contains more than 1 word.

Here is the code I wrote (the main part which is affected):

```
global issues_id_values

    mainIssues = issues_id()
    reportField.insert(END, mainIssues)

    def issues_id():
    global issue_page_value
        global issues_id_values
        global issues_titles_values
        global issues_status_values
        global issue_values_value

        titlesList = []
        td_title_span = 3
        if_component = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="xxx-header-row"]/th[3]').text
        print(if_component)
        comp_text = 'Component'
        if (if_component == comp_text):
            td_title_span = 4
        #issues_id_values = issues_id()
        for ids_to_titles in bugsList:
            zz = ids_to_titles
            bug_title_path = '//*[@id="xxx-' + zz + '"]/td[' + str(td_title_span) + ']/span'
            get_issue_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(bug_title_path)
            for title in get_issue_title:

                bb = str(title.text)
                titlesList.append('%s' % ''.join(map(str, bb)))

        return titlesList
```

Attach a screenshot showing what I get. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh7gI.png)

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? I feel it's something obvious to use which I don't see. Replace method didn't work as well as format but perhaps I used it incorrectly.

I would like to remove the curly brackets (as specified in the title) to get such result: [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3HkD.png)

Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem with your code? And add  expected output

Comment: I want to get rid of the {}.

Added a screenshot showing the expected result I'd like to get.

The point is this line didn't help me with this:

titlesList.append('%s' % ''.join(map(str, bb)))

Comment: I found a help there, indeed, @stovfl. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

I was able to fix the problem by adding such code:

```
 for xx in issues_id():
        reportField.insert(END, xx[:])
        reportField.insert(END, '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```py
import re

for title in get_issue_title:
    bb = str(title.text)
    titlesList.append(re.sub(r'{*}*', '', bb))
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, unfortunately. I still get the { } at the begining and end of the items from the list.

Comment: can you share the output

Comment: It was literally the same as before.